# Markdown editing help mentions syntax highlighting that doesn't exist

Tags: bug, status-completed

On https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting, you can notice examples for using syntax highlighting tags. Let me try them, as the documentation mentions them.

```
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

Nope, they don't work (you can check the source code of this post to confirm that), even if the editing help mentions them. It would be nice if either editing help would have this part removed, or if syntax highlighting tags would actually work.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to have been written for StackOverflow: it talks about inferring language from a tag, but I doubt that that has been configured for CodeGolf. However, I'm mildly surprised that `lang-cs` doesn't work:

```cs
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

At least some code highlighting does work, because you can [see it in action](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6838/194).